# When does OS X move /usr/local during a system update (slow start with homebrew)?

Tags: macos, software-update, homebrew

I have had a recurrent problem with the login screen getting stuck at 50% for a long time. One possible cause is that after an update, OS X is attempting to move /usr/local out of the way and then put it back. As I have many files installed there with homebrew, the update can take many hours.  This is certainly true for OS X upgrades as reported [here](https://jimlindley.com/blog/yosemite-upgrade-homebrew-tips/).

However, I've also seen this problem for what seem like minor system updates (e.g. Printer software upgrades). Does anybody know if OS X always try to move usr/local out of the way, even for minor updates?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue for `x.y.z` updates, only for `x.y` upgrades. This was especially painful for the last Yosemite upgrade.

Comment: Wesley, thanks. I saw this too. After further research, I found /usr/local was unrelated to the issue affecting my machine.